# My ajax code get only one value from a group of hidden inputs

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, dom

So basically I have this html document, generated dinamically by php code (foreach) that extracts rows of different comments (with different user id for each authors) and I stored cid (comment's id) and uid (user id of comment's author) in a group of hidden input:

hidusr = auth id

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>

                                    

                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="banusr"
                                        class="btn btn-info btn-link pull-right "> <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
                                        Ban</a>

                                    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="hidusr" name="uid"
                                        value="<?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars($comment['idauth'])) ?>" />
                                <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['text']); ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So the result in a web page it's like this:

```
<a href="utenti.php?id=2"> Author Name  </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="banusr"  class="btn btn-info btn-link pull-right "> <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
                                            Ban</a>
                                      
     <input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="hidusr" name="uid" value="2" />

<a href="utenti.php?id=9"> Other Author Name  </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="banusr"  class="btn btn-info btn-link pull-right "> <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
                                            Ban</a>
                                      
     <input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="hidusr" name="uid" value="9" />
```

Now I have some javascript/jquery code that manage this, at the click of Ban button, ajax takes hidusr param (so the author of that comment) and send request to php page that bans that user, an extract:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    bans = $(".banusr");

        for (var i = 0; i < bans.length; i++) {

            ban = bans[i];

            ban.onclick = function(e) {

                    uid = $("#hidusr").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "./ajax/ban.php?post",
                        data: {
                            
                            usr_uid: uid
                        }
});
```

But I don't know why, if you start banning users from up to down in the comments serie, it's okay, code takes correct id.

So I ban first from up: Ajax response in Headers: usr_uid: 2
Then I goes down, click ban: Ajax response in Headers: usr_uid 9

But if I click from down, example: I press Ban for last comment ("Other Author Name", hidusr: 9) Ajax response in Headers: usr_uid 2

Anyone knows how to resolve this, thanks in advance

Comment: It appears you have IDs with the same name. In HTML, IDs must be unique. So, lines like `uid = $("#hidusr").val();` may have unexpected results as there are more than 1 `hidusr` id.

Comment: @Twisty And How can I resolve this? Because I need an input that store uid different from each author of comment

Comment: Use a class instead of ID and then use $(this) to determine which element was clicked.

Comment: @RobMoll I don't know what you mean...can you post an example please, I tried insert value uid in ban button and then call in ajax with $(this).val() it doesn't work. I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider how your PHP constructs the page. It is setting the IDs for the HTML, so your loops should create Unique IDs.

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
?>
<a href="#" class="banusr" class="btn btn-info btn-link pull-right ">
  <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Ban
</a>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="hidusr-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="uid[]" value="<?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars($comment['idauth'])) ?>" />
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['text']); ?></p>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Now each ID will be unique: hiduser-1, hiduser-2, etc...

I also updated the `name` attribute, so that it collects all of them when the form is submitted, `name="uid[]"`.

Now your HTML will look something like:

```
<a href="#" class="banusr" class="btn btn-info btn-link pull-right ">
  <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Ban
</a>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="hidusr-1" name="uid[]" value="2" />
<a href="#" class="banusr" class="btn btn-info btn-link pull-right ">
  <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Ban
</a>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="hidusr-2" name="uid[]" value="9" />
```

So now we can look at the JavaScript.

```
$(function() {
  $(".banusr").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var uid = $(this).next("input").val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "./ajax/ban.php?post",
      data: {
        usr_uid: uid
      }
    });
  });
});
```

With this, we bind a `click` event callback to all the Ban links. Using `this`, we can select the next element that is an `input`, relative to the link that was clicked.

See More:

- https://learn.jquery.com/events/
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

In my opinion, there does not appear to be a need to hide the ID in an `input`. I would simply place it in the Link itself.

```
<?php 
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
?>
<a href="<?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars($comment['idauth'])) ?>" class="banusr" class="btn btn-info btn-link pull-right ">
  <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Ban
</a>
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['text']); ?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

You can then simplyfy the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".banusr").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "./ajax/ban.php?post",
      data: {
        usr_uid: $(this).attr("href")
      }
    });
  });
});
```